# I can't see or interact any vertices or faces on an imported FBX Model

Tags: bones, vertices, faces, .fbx

I'm trying to learn Blender in order to create character models for a game I really like. I have access to the game's models as .FBX files and their textures as standard sprite sheets. However, each time I import the model into blender I can't seem to interact with any of the model's faces or vertices. I can interact with the model's bones (or skeleton or whatever its called) but I can't interact with the model itself.  I'm still in the process of learning how to use blender to its fullest so pardon if its a silly question.

Comment: After looking into how to import textures onto the model, I also find that I'm unable to create any nodes in the Shading workspace. The option to add new nodes is just greyed out. I'm assuming these issues are interlinked with one another but if they aren't then I'd like some help for this too (but if I have to make a second post then I will make a second post)

Comment: I do not know if it is a silly question, it would really help if you showed some screenshots because so I can only return silly questions like: if you can interact with the bones/armature but not the faces or vertices: did you try this while the armature is selected or the mesh object? Did you try to go into _Edit Mode_ or was it _Object Mode_? Did you try to add nodes without having a material in the _Shader Editor_? Did you try to add nodes or a material while the armature was selected? And many more possible questions since we cannot know how much you already learned about these things.

Comment: So it turns out that a silly answer was just what I needed. When I was going into edit mode, I had the bones/armature selected as well as the mesh. I wasn't aware that I couldn't edit the mesh if I had all of it connected. The moment I just selected the mesh and switched over to Edit Mode, I could see the faces just fine. I noticed that sometimes I was able to edit the mesh while having the bones connected but I don't think that should be much of an issue. Thanks for the help! https://i.imgur.com/mc8s6Pv.png

Comment: Sometimes when multiple objects are selected it can also be a matter of which object is the active one, i.e. the one with the brighter outline.

Answer (score 0):

When I was going into edit mode, I had the bones/armature selected as well as the mesh. I wasn't aware that I couldn't edit the mesh if I had all of it connected. The moment I just selected the mesh and switched over to Edit Mode, I could see the faces just fine.

(With thanks to [Gordon Brinkmann](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/99859/gordon-brinkmann))